# How to use Table to assign values to variables in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, variable

I'm trying to do the following:

```
R = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
Table[R[[n]] = RandomInteger[{0, 20}], {n, 1, Length[R]}]
```

My intention is to assign a random value to each of these variables. But somehow it's not working. What else do I need to do? I've tried to do:

```
ToExpression[R[[n]] = RandomInteger[{0, 30}]]
```

And:

```
Evaluate[R[[n]] = RandomInteger[{0, 30}]]
```

Comment: Hello Gustavo, you'll want to avoid assigning things to capital letters. That being said, try `Scan[(# = RandomInteger[{0, 30}]) &, R]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that = is really Set, and Set is a pretty ordinary function. Also, RandomInteger can make a list all by itself, so you don't need Table.

Edit 11/15: Jerry Guern pointed out the need to be careful with quoting to have it work repeatedly. Here, I use `Unevaluated` to quote each variable:

```
r = Unevaluated /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
```

Now, you may use `r` repeatedly as input to:

```
MapThread[Set, {r, RandomInteger[{0, 20}, Length[r]]}];
```

Comment: But you can only do this once.  If you try to use the 2nd line a second time, it fails.