# How to re-assign values to a List of variables?

Tags: list-manipulation, variable

The accepted Answer to this similar [Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84284/how-to-use-table-to-assign-values-to-variables-in-a-list) can only be used one time, so it's not suitable for my problem.

I do high-dimensional calculations for which I need to make lists of variables, like so:

```
aa = Table[a[j], {j, 0, 12}];
```

This allows me to use the list as arguments for derivatives, like so:

```
D[p,{aa}]
```

But I need to be able to assign values to the variables in the list.  The following was offered as a solution to this in a different [Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84284/how-to-use-table-to-assign-values-to-variables-in-a-list):

```
MapThread[Set, {aa, RandomReal[1, 13]}];
Print[a[0], " ", a[1], " ", a[2]];
```

(* 0.211593 0.467789 0.572727 *)

If you use that command again, it tries to assign the value to the values instead of the variable.

```
MapThread[Set, {aa, RandomReal[1, 13]}];
```

(* Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 0.21159339034304447`. *)

So how can I change I reassign those values?

Comment: It's a pretty bad setup that you have, but if you insist on using it, here is one way: `Hold[aa] /. OwnValues[aa] /. Hold[elems_List] :>
  With[{vals = RandomReal[1, 13]}, Set @@@ Thread[Hold[elems, vals], List]]`. The complexity of this construction should be a convincing enough argument to avoid the setup like that. Things would totally simplify if you simply assign to `a[i]` in a loop. Not to mention that having one and the same variable stand for symbolic entity in differentiation and also be a variable storing a numerical value, doesn't sound like the best thing to do.

Comment: A slightly simpler and more elegant solution would be this: `Hold[aa] /. OwnValues[aa] /.  Hold[elems_List] :> Function[Null, Set[##], {HoldFirst, Listable}][elems,RandomReal[1, 13]]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  If I knew a better setup, I'd use it.  The key thing is, when I calculate gradients and Hessians, I want to be able to just use `D[p,{aa}]` instead of writing out a huge variable list.

Comment: Alternatively, if you insist on using a[j] as both a variable of integration and a variable to store numeric values, clear the values between the alternate assignments, i.e., `Clear[a,aa]`.

Comment: @bills  I truly don't insist on anything.  Is there some way I can a[j] as a variable of integration but then substitute numerical values, without having to write out /.{a[0]->value, a[1]->value, a[2]->value}?

Comment: @Karsten7.  Because then aa would be a list of numbers instead of a list of variables that have values.

Comment: In that case one could use `Evaluate[aa] = RandomReal[1, 13]` and something like `MapIndexed[(a[First@#2 - 1] = #1) &, RandomReal[1, 13]]`.

Comment: `(a[# - 1] =.) & /@ Range[Length@aa];` can be used to [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html) the individual indexed variables before re-setting them.

Comment: Maybe using `Thread[aa -> RandomReal[1, 13]]` together with `/.` instead of setting and re-setting values makes thinks easier overall.

Comment: Well, given your clarification: *" Is there some way I can a[j] as a variable of integration but then substitute numerical values, without having to write out /.{a[0]->value, a[1]->value, a[2]->value}? "*, all you have to do is this: do *not* assign the values on the top level, keeping `a[i]` symbolic. Instead, compute with numerical values as `Block[{a}, Evaluate[aa] = RandomReal[1, 13]; your-code]`. This way you localize the numerical substitutions to the body of the `Block`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want to do, so I will take a stab. Here are your variables`aa` and I"ve made up a function p[aa] for concreteness.

```
aa = Table[a[j], {j, 5}];
p[aa_] := aa^Range[Length[aa]] + Reverse[aa]  Range[Length[aa]]^3;
```

This allows you to take derivatives as desired:

```
sol = D[p[aa], {aa}]
```

To now plug-in values for the a[j], you can do:

```
sol //. Thread[aa -> Range[5]]
```

which gives the derivative evaluated at the desired points.