# Assignment via iteration over list of variables to be assigned values

Tags: evaluation, assignment, hold

Variations on my question have been asked before ([How to re-assign values to a List of variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99486/how-to-re-assign-values-to-a-list-of-variables), [How to use Table to assign values to variables in a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84284/how-to-use-table-to-assign-values-to-variables-in-a-list), [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6511/assigning-values-to-a-list-of-variable-names), [Pass the list of variables into function to change their values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58355/pass-the-list-of-variables-into-function-to-change-their-values)), but I'm not sure if any of them exactly cover my issue.

```
((#1 = 1) &) /@ {a, b, c}
```

sets `a`, `b`, and `c` to 1.  However, the similar-looking

```
Do[x = 1, {x, {a, b, c}}]
```

does nothing.  I assume this is because "`Do` effectively uses `Block` to localize values or variables", as stated in the documentation.  But once the values have been set, neither approach works to change their values:

```
((#1 = #1^2) &) /@ {a, b, c}
```

gives the error message "Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.", and

```
(If[EvenQ[#1], #1 = #1^2] &) /@ {a, b, c}
```

returns `{Null, Null, Null}` without changing anything.  (The equivalent `Do` versions don't do anything, as I expected.)  Do I need to use `Hold` or `Unevaluated` or something to get Mathematica to reassign the variables?

Comment: [Dupe?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some methods:

```
Replace[Hold[a, b, c], v_ :> (v = 2), 1] // ReleaseHold;
{a, b, c}

Replace[Hold[a, b, c], v_ :> (v = v^2), 1] // ReleaseHold;
{a, b, c}
(*
  {2, 2, 2}
  {4, 4, 4}
*)

Function[v, v = 3, HoldAll] /@ Hold[a, b, c] // ReleaseHold;
{a, b, c}

Function[v, v = v^2, HoldAll] /@ Hold[a, b, c] // ReleaseHold;
{a, b, c}
(*
  {3, 3, 3}
  {9, 9, 9}
*)

SeedRandom[1];
Do[x /. Hold[v_] :> (v = RandomReal[]), {x, List @@ Hold /@ Hold[a, b, c]}]
{a, b, c}

Do[x /. Hold[v_] :> (v = v^2), {x, List @@ Hold /@ Hold[a, b, c]}]
{a, b, c}
(*
  {0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526}
  {0.668126, 0.0124143, 0.623351}
*)
```

---

An alternative is to use replacement rules (a `List` or `Association`) or `Block` to insert values when needed.  One has to keep the symbols `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. undefined. Here are examples with [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html):

```
Clear[a, b, c]

val = <||>;

(val[#] = 2) & /@ {a, b, c};
{a, b, c} /. val
(*  {2, 2, 2}  *)

MapThread[
  (val[#] = #2) &,
  {{a, b, c}, -Range@3}];
{a, b, c} /. val
(*  {-1, -2, -3}  *)

Map[
  (val[#] = val[#]^2) &,
  {a, b, c}];
{a, b, c} /. val
(*  {1, 4, 9}  *)

val
(*  <|a -> 1, b -> 4, c -> 9|>  *)

b^2 - 4 a c /. val
(*  -20  *)
```