# How to use Set correctly

Tags: evaluation, assignment

My codes are shown in the picture attached.

I'm writing codes for numerical calculations frequently, and I think it looks neat and clear to organize input parameters in the form of table. For example,

```
calcTable=Grid[{{gridNum, tWindow, calcStepPerStep, dataSavingStep}, 
            {8192, 200.*tPulse, 32, 32}}, Dividers -> All]

MapThread[Set, {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}] & @ calcTable;
```

This would be displayed in a form of table in the frontend, and I can easily check and change every parameter.

However, if I want change some of the parameters displayed in the table after I have run the program once, warning appears, and no change of the values can be observed.

I think there must be some misunderstanding in the usage of `Set` in the `MapThread`. It can be seen that during the evalutation of

```
 MapThread[Set, {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}] & @
       calcTable;
```

parameters such as `{gridNum, tWindow, calcStepPerStep, dataSavingStep}` has been assigned with its value at the first place.

Actually, I'd like the evaluation performed in this way, first take `{gridNum, tWindow, calcStepPerStep, dataSavingStep}` literrally, then use `Set` to assigned values to them by `MapThread`. I think this is closely related to nonstandard evaluation. But how can I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: closely related: [**103263**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103263/5478) and a possible duplicate: [**84284**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84284/5478).

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally this is a very common question:

- [Reassign values to symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280/121)
- [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/121)
- [How to pass a symbol name to a function with any of the Hold attributes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2651/121)
- [MapThread gives different results from ToExpression when trying to assign variables from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2926/121)
- [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)
- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)

The defined Symbols are evaluating before `Set` ever sees them.

I would need to see how you are actually using this to make a proper recommendation but for the single example given you might wrap the entire thing in [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) the [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) like this:

```
calcTable = 
 Grid[
   {{gridNum, tWindow, calcStepPerStep, dataSavingStep}, {8192, 200.*tPulse, 32, 32}},
   Dividers -> All
 ] // HoldForm

Set @@@ calcTable[[{1}, 1]] // ReleaseHold
```

You can redefine the Symbols with a second table:

```
calcTable2 = 
 Grid[
   {{gridNum, tWindow, calcStepPerStep, dataSavingStep}, {foo, bar, 3.14, 42}},
   Dividers -> All
 ] // HoldForm

Set @@@ calcTable2[[{1}, 1]] // ReleaseHold
```

The Symbols have the new definitions:

```
{gridNum, tWindow, calcStepPerStep, dataSavingStep}
```

> ```
> {foo, bar, 3.14, 42}
> ```

I find this a rather clumsy way to handle Symbol assignment however and I imagine that a different approach will ultimately be superior.  (Please see the referenced Q&A's for examples.)